# How to exclude a user from being randomized with Math.random() if it already exists in database

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, loops, object

As part of a school project we are creating an application where users can match with each other if they play the same game. When you click on matchButton a random user that plays the game you have chosen will show up on the page. You can choose to like that user or continue hitting the matchButton to randomize another user.

**Now we want to make sure that a user you have already liked won't be randomized and therefore not be rendered on the page.**

The users that have been liked are saved in an array called match in the database, for each user. 
The users that play the same game are saved in an array called numOfMatches. So it is numOfMatches that we use to randomize a user.

I think I have to loop through numOfMatches and the match array in the database to see if the user in numOfMatches is already in the database. If so, I need to remove the user from numOfMatches so that it is not included in Math.random code.

I tried with this code in the last function in this post, but I am having a problem with understanding how to reach the elements in the match array in the users object and how to use splice (and in which function I should place the code since we use callbacks which I think is a bit tricky):

```
for(let i = 0; i < numOfMatches.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < users[j].match.length; j++) {
        if(numOfMatches[i] === users[j].match) {
          let position = numOfMatches.indexOf(randomUser)
             numOfMatches.splice(position, 1)
        }
    }
}
```

I am very thankful for ideas and suggestions.

Sample from database:

```
{
   "username":"bobox",
   "email":"bobox@hotmail.com",
   "password":"test234",
   "gender":"Man",
   "age":"17",
   "city":"Jönköping",
   "games":"Battlefield V",
   "usernameDiscord":"bigbox",
   "usernameSteam":"bigbox",
   "usernameOrigin":"bobox",
   "match":[
      "carro",
      "arooma",
      "gamer_girl"
   ],
   "_id":"WRa86pRsVex6NBe2"
}
```

---

```
function renderMatches(users) {
    let bigDiv = document.querySelector(".TheBigDiv")
    let matches = document.querySelector(".Match__List")
    let matchGames = document.querySelector(".Match__Games")
    let matchButton = document.querySelector(".Match__Button")
    let noMatch = document.createElement("h3")

    matchButton.addEventListener("click", async(event) => {
        hanna(users)
    })
}

function randomMatches(numOfMatches, users) {
    let bigDiv = document.querySelector(".TheBigDiv")
    let matches = document.querySelector(".Match__Lis")
    console.log("numOfMatches:", numOfMatches)

    bigDiv.innerHTML = ""
    console.log("Funkar här")
    let newClone = matches.cloneNode(true)
    let randomUser = numOfMatches[Math.floor(Math.random() * numOfMatches.length)]

    newClone.querySelector('.Match-Username').innerHTML = randomUser.username
    newClone.querySelector('.Match-Age').innerHTML = randomUser.age
    newClone.querySelector('.Match-Game').innerHTML = "Spelar:" + " " + randomUser.games
    newClone.classList.remove("Prototype")
    bigDiv.append(newClone)

    likeUser(randomUser, users)
}


function hanna(users) {
    console.log(users)
    let numOfMatches = []
    let matchGames = document.querySelector(".Match__Games")
    let matches = document.querySelector(".Match__Lis")
    let bigDiv = document.querySelector(".TheBigDiv")
    let noMatch = document.createElement("h3")
    for (let j = 0; j < users.length; j++) {
        let currentUser = users[j]
        let UserID = currentUser._id
        let gejm = matchGames.querySelector(".gejms").value
        if (currentUser.games == gejm) {
            console.log("users:", currentUser)
            console.log(currentUser._id)
            numOfMatches.push(currentUser)
            console.log("hej")
            randomMatches(numOfMatches, users)

        }
    }
    if (numOfMatches.length == 0) {
        noMatch.innerHTML = "No matches found"
        bigDiv.append(noMatch)
    }

}
```

Comment: you want to *exclude* the user you like? sound not right to me :/

Comment: if it's in the db, you can simply do that in query, something like `select * from playing_user[game_id] except like_user[user_id,game_id]` to get a filtered list

Comment: Is it backend JavaScript? is it server in Node.js, do you fetch users once and that process it and it's in memory? Or is in some other request language like PHP. I would just fetch all the users into array save that in session and remove the users that was already liked. You don't need to save that into database unless like function is like on Facebook where it's permanent. What type of database you're using? How many users you have and how many users you need to support?

Comment: my code is meant to be (pseudo code) SQL. which fetch all candidate user from database. This method would not fit for large scale application directly, though.

Comment: if all you need if filter an javascript array, simply use `Array.filter` ti filter out those you don't want. something like `[1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(x=>x%2!=0)`

Comment: So each time someone clicks on matchButton the users start to randomly appear on the page. I want to exclude a user from being rendered with Math.random() if it has already been liked and added to database. So that is what I meant with excluding a user.

Comment: The code I posted here is from frontend javascript but we are using backend javascript as well where we have our routes. Yes, we are using node.js. No PHP, just Javascript. The database is nedb. Since it is only a school project we have created users from dummy data. Right now we have 10 users but we will add more. Could you be more specific with what you mean by fetch users into an array? In which function can I do this? @jcubic

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Array.filter @appleapple I am just no sure how to write it in this case. I guess it is still numOfMatches i need to filter?

Comment: @jcubic I think we have to save the likes in the database as they are stored on each users profile until the user deletes a like from its profile.

Comment: IF you have node.js all it mean that you have state for every user that open the app, you can just use let users = db.query('select all users') when user first open the app, if he like the user you just use `users = users.filter((x) => x.id !== selectedUser);` filter will run on all users but this is fine, if it will slow thigs down you can optimize it to `find` and `splice` or if you don't know how to use those two functions you can use for loop and when found the item you break the loop. PS: By fetch I mean get all users from database into array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example.

```js
const candidate = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
const exclude = [1,3,7]

let target = candidate.filter(x=>!exclude.includes(x))
console.log(target)

console.log(target[Math.floor(Math.random() * target.length)])
```